Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS cant use sudo, wifi disappear, can't reinstall ubuntu
I think I messed up, I can't use sudo, it says:
sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is world writable  
sudo : /use/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set 

When I try to reinstall my Ubuntu, the message says:
incorrect permission on/use/libexec/polkit-agent-helper-1 (needs to be setuid root)


You're without Ubuntu product & release details, meaning we can only be generic. If an issue is detected in regards sudo the sudoers file is stopped from being read at that point; if its permissions related then nothing will be read. This however won't impact an re-install as install media is RO & thus any mistakes are made only in RAM, and a reboot of install media should resolve any mistake. If you've tried that, did you verify your media is valid?  (ie. ISO validation?  check the ISO write was correct? or media scan completed? for your unstated Ubuntu product/release)

I note you've added release details (22.04.4) but still no product details; ie. Server?  (thus you're asking about the subiquity installer), or Desktop?  (thus you're asking about the ubiquity installer)... ie. please be specific with details.  Did you verify ISO? as per documentation? or write of ISO to media (that takes seconds, and if not perfect you'll save loads of time worrying about problems such as what you're doing now.. as it shows the problem that needs solving). Your error (if on install media as you mention install) highlights bad media so I suggest check it.

How did you 'mess up' the  file-permissions ? And how do you try to re-install ? Normally you should boot from live-media (USB, DVD ..) and then choose 'Install Ubuntu' ..

Does this answer your question? /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

Try this solution:

Log out from Ubuntu
Log in as root
Execute the following command: chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
Log out
Log in using the user profile you use.


By default 'root' is disabled in Ubuntu, so this might not be possible.

This is actually possible if you reboot to recovery
